# How to increase height of uiview when auto layout is enabled in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I tried turning off auto layout for specific sub-views in interface builder at runtime programmatically using below code.

```
[view removeConstraints:view.constraints];
```

Somewhere someone suggested to do this:

> If you need to change the height of a view with auto layout active, you'll need to create an IBOutlet for your height constraint and modify that at runtime, i.e.:
>
> ```
> @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
> self.heightConstraint.constant = 200
> ```

Yet I don't understand what this means.

Comment: Do not try and resize the view. That's impossible. Instead... only try to resize constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add :

```
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

to your code after you changed your height constraint. it will refresh the view and the constraint.
It simply means that instead of removing autolayout you can keep it to your view and create a constraint to change the height dynamically.

You can follow this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) to understand how autolayout works

Comment: i used following code.

    [myview removeConstraints:myview.constraints];
    CGRect newFrame = vyview.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = 650;
    [myview setFrame:newFrame];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

myview is itself contains inside uiscrollview, and the last line is giving error, i guess self is not recognised by system.
please tell me the issue.

Comment: You should not remove actual contraint. but use existing one and change it programaticaly. First, you create iboutlet of you constraint, then you change the height.constant and finaly you use method layoutifneed as mentioned before. Do not remove constraint. Also  Forget frame.

Comment: Forget that the frame property exists. Never set it directly. A view’s frame is the result of the Auto Layout process, not an input variable. To change the frame, change the constraints. This forces you to change the way you think about your UI. Rather than thinking in positions and sizes, think of the rules that specify a each view’s positioning in relation to its siblings and parents. It’s not unlike CSS.

Comment: Thanks Gregory Molette. your explanation guided me in right direction.

Comment: You are welcome. just use autolayout OR Frame never both together. Tought, it s recomanded to use autolayout now. Because there is many size and resolution on apple device now.

Answer (score 1):

Please read and understand Apple's documentation on auto layout.

For now, if you remove all constraints, that does not disable auto layout.

You need to reference the height constraint in code and modify it as suggested, then `[view layoutIfNeeded]` as suggested by other answers.

If there is no height constraint yet, you may also add a new one at runtime via `addConstraints:`.

Can you elaborate on what exactly it is you are missing to follow your cited suggestion?

**Edit**:
Please also note that the suggestion you cited is in swift, not Obj-C, so copy & paste won't do the trick.

**Edit 2**:

Here we go, word by word.

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

- `@IBOutlet`: The following variable declaration's value is to be injected from the interface builder. Hooked up via drag and drop.
- `weak`: Keyword in both Obj-C and Swift. The reference count is not increased nor managed by the assignment or use of this variable. (cf. 'retain-cycle' and 'memory management'.)
- `var`: This declaration's value may be reassigned after it's initialization. In contrast to `let`; in Swift, variables can be declared immutable.
- `heightConstraint`: The name of the declared variable
- `:`: read as 'of type'
- `NSLayoutConstraint!`: Type of the variable declared. In this case an implicitly unwrapped optional of `NSLayoutConstraint`. This roughly translates to the Obj-C type `NSLayoutConstraint*`.

Now,

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = 200
```

sets the constant of the above declared variable somewhere in the code when is suits you. In this example to `200`.

Comment: i what i was trying to say is i don't understand what this code snippet means.

Comment: i commented above can you please check and tell me whats wrong with my code.

Comment: I updated my answer to include exhaustive details of explaination of the code. Can you pinpoint the problem you are having in terms of understanding now?

Comment: The issue you are having (please do not post code as a comment; rather edit your question) is: You still try to remove all constraints. I already told you that this does not disable auto layout. Stick with modifying the constraints, do not fight the system.

Comment: Thanks Jan Greve, your atomic explanation and Gregory expalantion did the trick and it worked. i was stuck in this from like ages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add after setting constraint values.

```
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! 
self.heightConstraint.constant = 200
```

constant:
The constant added to the multiplied second attribute participating in the constraint.

Unlike the other properties, the constant can be modified after constraint creation.

**Setting the constant on an existing constraint performs much better than removing the constraint** and adding a new one that's exactly like the old except that it has a different constant.

Comment: The question is in Obj-C, not in swift.

Comment: Be the same in my Dash.

Comment: `@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! ` this will not be recognized for Obj-C :)

Answer (score 0):

After getting help from Gregory and Jan now i am able to explain it step by step.

1) Drag the height constraint of the uiView to your .h file.

2) Then refrence it with a name, in my case i use heightConstraint.

3) Use following code to do the trick.

```
_heightConstraint.constant = 650;
[_myview layoutIfNeeded];
```